# Missing indication that question was migrated

Tags: feature-request, migration

The question https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/how-draw-a-add-two-shape was posted on Meta and then closed as off-topic. Apparently it was also migrated to the main site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126884/how-draw-an-add-two-shape. On that question, there's a note that the question was migrated from Meta, but on the original question, there's no indication of the migration.

I seem to recall that in the past, there would be some kind of note on the original question that points to the questions new location.

Would it be possible to get that back?

Comment: This may be a consequence of a special situation - where migration lead to closure.